# Visualizing time-series from a SQL Database (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql, time-series, influxdb, grafana, pipelinedb

I am building an app that applies a datascience model on a SQL Database, for sensor metrics. For this purpose I chose PipelineDB (based on Postgres) that enables me to build a Continuous View on my metrics and apply the model to each new line.

For now, I just want to observe the metrics I collect through the sensor on a dashboard. The table "metrics" looks like this :

```
+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-----+
| timestamp           | T (°C) | P (bar) | n    | ... |
+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-----+
| 2015-12-12 20:00:00 | 20     | 1.13    | 0.9  |     |
+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-----+
| 2015-12-13 20:00:00 | 20     | 1.132   | 0.9  |     |
+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-----+
| 2015-12-14 20:00:00 | 40     | 1.131   | 0.96 |     |
+---------------------+--------+---------+------+-----+
```

I'd like to build a dashboard in which I could see all my metric evolving through time. Even be able to choose which column to display.

So I found a few tools that could match with my need, which are Grafana or Chronograf for InfluxDB.
But neither of them enable me to plug directly on Postgres and query my table to generate metric-formatted data that is required by these tools.

**Do you have any advice on what I should do to use such dashboards with such data ?**

Comment: You can write your own grafana storage driver (plugin), as far as I know and maybe there are already examples for relational databases that exist in the repository. First time I'm hearing about PipelineDb, looks similar to Spark. Is column `n` result of the model? How complex is the model itself in terms of formula?

Comment: This is Jeff from PipelineDB. A frontend integration for Grafana or something similar is on our roadmap but won't be ready this quarter. We should have something available during Q2 of this year, however. If you have specific questions feel free to email us at info@pipelinedb.com. We're happy to help you figure something out in the meantime.

Comment: I've not used Pipeline, is it supposed to be an equivalent to Firebase?

Comment: Hey ! Thanks for your answers. Since I just need a POC for now, I formatted data from PipelineDB to InfluxDB to display them on Grafana. 
For now it's enough, and when the PipelineDB->Grafana connector will be out, I'll use it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late here, but Grafana now supports Postgresql datasources directly: https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/postgres.  I've used it in several projects and it has been really easy to set up and use.